# Why query is showing system error?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query, I want to write it in php but its showing error.

My query is like below:

```
$exe1 = mysql_query("
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(CASE WHEN `size_name` = ''',
      `size_name`,
      ''' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS `',
      `size_name`, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM Size;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT st.Style , ', @sql, '
                  FROM Size s
                  JOIN Style st ON s.style_id = st.id
                   GROUP BY st.Style 
                  ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;") or die(mysql_error());
```

But its showing the message

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT st.Style , ', @sql, ' FROM Size s ' at
>   line 12

I just dont know how to solve this error. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: mysql_query only supports single statements,

Comment: You **cannot** do multiple queries using the `mysql_*` functions, and they're also **deprecated**

Comment: use `mysqli`, it supports `multi_query` to run.

Comment: I tried it,but when i am using while loop,its unable to fetch value,Like when i am using the code like below

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($exe1))
{
    print_r($row);
}

Its not showing any value in array.What to do @ Yogesh Suthar.

Comment: Is there any1 to get rid of there please

Answer (score 0):

You should print out the resulting query in `@sql` to see the problem.

In your case, you would seem to have an extra comma after the last argument.  Try changing the line:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT st.Style , ', @sql, '
                  FROM Size s
                  JOIN Style st ON s.style_id = st.id
                   GROUP BY st.Style 
                  ');
```

to:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT st.Style , ', @sql'
                  FROM Size s
                  JOIN Style st ON s.style_id = st.id
                   GROUP BY st.Style 
                  ');
```

Comment: Its not working,remain same error. @Gordon Linoff.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query does not support multiple queries.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

mysql_* functions are deprecated and will be deleted. I advise you to use mysqli_* functions or PDO.